# Change the algorithm used in the TLS in the Firefox

Tags: firefox, firefox-addon

Can I change the algorithm used in the TLS in the Firefox by a XUL Extension? I conjecture, that it is impossible, if so please describe the best way to make it.

Comment: I'm not sure what TLS is, can you tell me more about it, and give us some code, I'm sure I can help with it, I just need some direction.

Comment: I don't have any code now, because I'm just planning the development of my extension. [TLS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Transport_Layer_Security). I want to find out, what is the best way to change the algorithm used in this part of Mozilla Firefox.